# How to check Objective-C 2.0 ARC in gnustep linux

Tags: automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-2.0

I wanna check [ARC write back](http://books.google.ru/books?id=iTQSWMJTkw4C&pg=PA70&lpg=PA70&dq=int%20writeBack%20objc&source=bl&ots=SP1BfzdVPA&sig=VJruCW4Nbwx808zA-qMj8R00yII&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=PNdTUcDmGcWm4ASEzoGoCA&ved=0CDcQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=int%20writeBack%20objc&f=false) in linux gnustep environment (I prepared that by [this article](http://etoileos.com/downloads/installtrunk/)).

I have **main.m** file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

__weak id obWeak;

int writeBack(id *);

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        id object;
    writeBack(&object);
    NSLog(@"object(%@) weak(%@)", object, obWeak);
    object=nil;
    NSLog(@"object(%@) weak(%@)", object, obWeak);
    }
    NSLog(@"weak %@", obWeak);
    return 0;
}

int writeBack(id * aValue){
    *aValue=[NSObject new];
    obWeak = *aValue;
    return 0;
}
```

**GNUmakefile**:

```
include $(GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES)/common.make

CC=clang

TOOL_NAME = CmdTest

${TOOL_NAME}_OBJCFLAGS = -fobjc-arc
${TOOL_NAME}_BUNDLE_LIBS += -lobjc -lgnustep-base
${TOOL_NAME}_OBJC_FILES = main.m

include $(GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES)/tool.make
```

and Linux **console output**:

```
2013-03-28 13:50:33.840 CmdTest[7751] object(<NSObject: 0x2068c38>) weak(<NSObject: 0x2068c38>)
2013-03-28 13:50:33.842 CmdTest[7751] object((null)) weak(<NSObject: 0x2068c38>)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

As you can see, I got **Segmentation fault (core dumped)** when I tried to call NSLog(@"weak %@", obWeak) from outside of @autoreleasepool block.

I've tried to compile this code at XCode on mac pc and didn't get any error. Could you help me to understand what's wrong with it?

Comment: No segfault here, a back trace could help. My libobjc2 is trunk@36228 and clang version 3.3 (trunk 176643)

Comment: Hmm... I reinstall environment and it's okay now.... =( sorry for asking